# Cookie set with old value

Tags: php, variables, cookies

I'm using the code:

```
IF (isset($_GET['s']))
{
    $sessie = $_GET['s'];
}
ELSE
{
    $sessie = 'I';
}
$cookie = 'JaiDje_Page';
setcookie($cookie, $sessie);
$WDpag = $_COOKIE[$cookie];
echo $WDpag."-".$_COOKIE[$cookie]."-".$sessie."<br>";
```

After a new value for $sessie (menu choise) the strange thing is that the first time the page is loaded,  $WDpag and $_COOKIE[$cookie] are giving the old value and $sessie is giving the new value.
After a page refresh all three values are the same.

So after making a choise in the menu the following is echos (exampel)

I-I-Z

than after a page refresh (F5)

Z-Z-Z

It seems that the cookie is one step behind the choise in my menu.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`$_COOKIE` is set when the page loads so If you want immediate access, you can set `$_COOKIE['variable']` direct.

so do like this

```
//setcookie($cookie, $sessie);
$_COOKIE[$cookie] = $sessie;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was together with the other answer the solution for more than one point! Great! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `$_COOKIE[$cookie]` returns the current cookie sent by the browser. While `setcookie` sends a cookie to the browser. When you retrieve the value `$_COOKIE[$cookie]`, the cookie is not yet set because it will be set after the page is requested.

try to put this after `setcookie`:

```
if($_COOKIE[$cookie] != $sessie) header("location: pageName.php");
```

Comment: Thanks, this was together with the other answer the solution for more than one point! Great! :-)